# Difference between a SegWit address and a P2SH address

Tags: segregated-witness, multi-signature, p2sh

Let there be an address `3ABCDEFGHJKDJHDH....`

How can I understand if it's a SegWit address or a MultiSig address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Until a P2SH-P2WPKH UTXO is spent and the redeemScript is exposed, a P2SH-P2WPKH address is indistinguishable from a non-segwit P2SH address (such as a non-segwit multi-signature address)

Reference: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/

That's because a P2SH address is still a *hash* of the script, regardless of whether the script is an embedded P2WPKH script or plain old script script. So you can't 'decode' it back into what the script is, you have to wait until the script itself is made public when redeeming the output.

Comment: yup, type 3 addresses are a hash of an input value, and with current technology it is nearly impossible, to reverse the function to see it's initial input.