# How do I determine whether an input or output is segwit? - revisited

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, transaction-input, witness-data

This is a discussion that has already been had [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68413/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-input-or-output-is-segwit), but bear with me.

We're gonna be talking about tx `faae7e55db14a32e083cbf6a91db8a5ab6a3b05e050d9cefdec80b47f966848e`

- all I got is the encoded transaction
- it has been marked as segwit (marker + flag)
- tx has 3 inputs, only the last one is segwit
- the segwit input has a script sig: `1600140c6259927541c4f8e88fc1398691e2661d15591a`
- got to decode the witnesses section correctly, implied there is `only one`

In the previous discussion, they mentioned that a segwit input is easily spotted as it has an empty script sig.

The segwit input we have here `has a script sig`... I know it's segwit cause I looked in a blockchain explorer. How can my software programatically tell it's segwit just by looking at the transaction's data?

Comment: Native segwit inputs have an empty scriptSig; P2SH-wrapped segwit inputs have a P2SH redeemScript in the scriptSig.

Comment: The way to determine whether an input has a witness is simply by seeing if it had witness data. I realize that's tautological, but there is nothing else to it: the BIP144 transaction serialization simply encodes the witness data for every input.

Comment: Ohhh I see, the witness section starts by 0, 0, 2... Thanks again @PieterWuille

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the BIP141 segwit rules consider transactions is simply that *every* transaction input (even non-segwit ones) have a witness stack. Non-segwit inputs are required to have an empty witness stack however.

If every transaction input has an empty witness stack, the old pre-segwit transaction serialization is used for the transaction. If at least one inout has a non-empty witness stack, the BIP144 transaction serialization format (including marker & flag) is used. The non-segwit inputs then simply have an empty witness.

Now, there is a consensus rule that says that unless a transaction input is a segwit spend, its witness stack *must* be empty. An input is a segwit spend if the UTXO it spends is a witness program (OP_n + push of 2-40 bytes), or if it is a P2SH UTXO, whose redeemScript is such a witness program. *If* an input is a segwit spend, the scriptSig *must* be exactly empty or exactly the P2SH redeemScript and nothing else. If an input is *not* a segwit spend, the witness stack must be empty. But all of this is rules that govern whether a transaction is valid w.r.t. its witnesses and scriptSigs; it is unrelated to whether the transaction *has* witnesses.

Comment: Thanks for getting me going... you're an invaluable asset for the Bitcoin industry!